# How to order 3 images horizontally?

Tags: graphics, examples

I use the following code to include three images:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{delete_gesture.png}
\caption{Awesome Image}
\label{fig:awesome_image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{ok_gesture.png}
\caption{Awesome Image}
\label{fig:awesome_image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{settings_gesture.png}
\caption{Awesome Image}
\label{fig:awesome_image}
\end{figure}
```

Now the images are ordered vertically. I want them horizontally. I tried to use `columns` or `multicols` but couldn't find a solution. Any hint?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

put them all together in *one* figure environment and the three minipages
without an empty line

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{delete_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image1}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ok_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image2}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{settings_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image3}
\endminipage
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh, golly -- please make those captions ragged right!  they don't need to be that spacy!

Comment: @Barbara: sorry, but the captions is incomplete: "A really awsame image and caption" ... :-)

Comment: I'm just trying this out now, with three identical images, and I get a strange problem where the center image is shifted down, due to the length of the caption. Is there a way to prevent this with captions of varying length?

Comment: How ahould the images be adjusted, at top or bottom?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't align vertically the images if the captions have different lengths, how to correct this?

Comment: every combination is possible!

Comment: OH!!! "without an empty line"!!!!!  That should be in bold!

Comment: How do you insert another row of minipages like 3 x 2?

Answer (score 14):

Here is a solution with `subfigure` package. It has 2 rows and 2 columns of images. The widths are chosen such that it fits into a column of a 2-column page. I guess you get the idea.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\subfigure[text]{
\includegraphics[width=.225\textwidth]{file}
}
\subfigure[text]{
\includegraphics[width=.225\textwidth]{file}
}

\subfigure[text]{
\includegraphics[width=.225\textwidth]{file}
}
\subfigure[text]{
\includegraphics[width=.225\textwidth]{file}
}

\caption{blablabla}
\label{fig:whatever}
\end{figure}
```

As you can see it's pretty simple to have to images/objects next to each other -- just put them into the same line. Or you can use `multicol` inside a `figure`.

**Please note that `subfigure` is superseded by `subfig` which provides `\subfloat` command instead of `\subfigure`.** More compatibility information is found in the `subfig` documentation.

Comment: Using subfigures is a good idea. I would prefer the `subfig` package, since it's newer than `subfigure` and it's widely considered as its successor.

Comment: according to wikipedia subfigure is depricated.

Comment: The `subcaption` package is the way to go now! It provides a `subfigure` environment and  the `\subcaptionbox` command.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, you just saved my day.

Answer (score 9):

I use the following technique:

```
\begin{figure}[h]       
    \fbox{\includegraphics{fig1.pdf}}   
    \hspace{30px}
    \fbox{\includegraphics{fig2.pdf}}
    \hspace{30px}
    \fbox{\includegraphics{fig3.pdf}}
    \caption{this is the caption}
    \label{materialflowChart}
\end{figure}
```

This places a thin line around each image (as it uses `framebox`). You can use `\mbox` in the same way if you don't want a frame. The `\hspace{}` command is a convenient way of controlling the spacing between the two images.

Comment: Some notes: `\label` always comes after `\caption`. I think you mean '30pt' not `30px`, but `\hfill` would be better.

Comment: @Martin: px is the pdf unit and exactly 1 pixel

Comment: Thanks Martin, I did not know that about `\label` - I swapped the order. For some reason 30px works on my computer - I thought the px dimensions could be supplied? Is this not the case?

Comment: @Herbert: thanks, I didn't know that pdftex is adding this unit. I had a short look in the TeXbook and run a test with `tex` beforehand. Should have used `pdftex` :-)

Comment: @Martin - Just curious, why is `\hfill` better?

Comment: @celenius: `\hfill` is not better, it depends of what you want. Often three images side by side take the whole line and it makes sense to push the outer ones strait to the line margin. If you have really small images, then it maybe better to center all and using a small gap between the images.

Comment: @celenius: As Herbert already said `\hfill` is only better if you have two or more larger images. I assumed that here. Note that in your code both images will be left aligned. As already mentioned normally a `\centering` is a good thing here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subfig package`. Just keep in mind, you may need to change the width value if you're working with two or more columns

```
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{figure}[!b]
      \centering
      \subfloat[text img1]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{img1.png}}
      \qquad
      \subfloat[text img2]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{img2.png}}
      \qquad
      \subfloat[text img3]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{img3.png}}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Remember that the `subfig` package has been obsolete for a very long time, and even its authors mentioned that it should no longer be used. Its last version is almost 20 years old, and its replacement is `subcaption`.

Comment: @Miyase [`subfigure`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) is obsolete. [`subfig`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) is still the official successor. Nevertheless I would also recommend to use [`subcaption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption).

Comment: @cabohah subfig's own CTAN page points to subcaption as a replacement.