# Latex figure numbering as part a,b,c

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am writing an article and I have to display figures side by side. I used the commands from the following link [How to order 3 images horizontally?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10245/how-to-order-3-images-horizontally) to do that. However, the figures are numbered in sequence, eg. Figure 1, Figure 2 Figure 3. I would like all of them to be part of same figure 1 and have subsections as (a) , (b) and (c).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 29):

You could also use the `subcaption` package and its `subfigure` environment. The following example sets up the subfigures so that they occupy the full width of the textblock. It also assumes that the graphs associated with each subfigure are all equally wide; if that's not the case, simply adjust the widths of the `subfigure`s appropriately.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' for real document

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig_a.pdf}
    \caption{First subfigure} \label{fig:1a}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hspace*{\fill}   % maximize separation between the subfigures
  \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig_b.pdf}
    \caption{Second subfigure} \label{fig:1b}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hspace*{\fill}   % maximizeseparation between the subfigures
  \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig_c.pdf}
    \caption{Third subfigure} \label{fig:1c}
  \end{subfigure}

\caption{A figure that contains three subfigures} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I always get the error "missing number, treated as zero", for `\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}` any ideas?

Comment: @IceFire - Do you load the `subcaption` or `subfig` package? (The answer shown above works only with the `subcaption` package...)

Answer (score 15):

You can use `subfig` package:

```
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\subfloat[subfig-a's caption]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{...}}
\subfloat[subfig-b's caption]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{...}}
\subfloat[subfig-c's caption]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{...}}
\caption{...}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Nice, but the subfig text is so tiny, how can I change that?

Comment: @Pedro77 Please refer to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365683/34848).