# How to vertically align 'subcaption' subfigures

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, subfloats, subcaption

I am using the `\usepackage{subcaption}` library (inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165728/latex-figure-numbering-as-part-a-b-c)) to create a figure with two images, like so:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.45 \linewidth}
    \centering
    \vfill
    \includegraphics{2020.jpg}
    \caption{A a $20\times 20$ image in original size.}
\end{subfigure} \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.54 \linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=6cm]{2020.jpg}
    \caption{The same images with increased resolution, for illustrative purposes.}
\end{subfigure}
```

Giving me the following:

[image]

How do I vertically align the two images? I.e. I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152818/top-aligned-subfigure-with-bottom-aligned-caption and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80172/align-captions-of-subfigures?s=7|0.0000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\subcaptionbox{<caption>}[<width>]{<image>}` instead the `subfigure` environments, then you get the desired result, no trickery needed.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{%
    A a $20\times 20$ image in original size.
  }[0.45\linewidth]
  {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-1x1}}
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{%
    The same images with increased resolution, for illustrative purposes.
  }[0.54 \linewidth]
  {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-1x1}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! :-) It is also possible to add a normal caption to both images (not part of the question, but good to know)

Comment: @TokeFaurby Do you mean what you get by adding `\caption{ ... }` after the second `\subcaptionbox`?