# Images stacked horizontally : unwanted vertical gap

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, blindtext

I am trying to stack three images horizontally. The images have the same size, I want to align them without any vertical gap. I followed the instructions that I found on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10247/22297):

```
\blindtext

    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \minipage{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Immagini/teiera-ambientale.png}
        \caption{Componente ambientale}
        \label{fig:Componente ambientale}
        \endminipage\hfill
        \minipage{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Immagini/teiera-diffusa.png}
        \caption{Componente ambientale e diffusa}
        \label{fig:Componente ambientale e diffusa}
        \endminipage\hfill
        \minipage{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Immagini/teiera-speculare.png}
        \caption{Componente ambientale, diffusa e speculare}
        \label{fig:Componente ambientale, diffusa e speculare}
        \endminipage
    \end{figure}

    \blindtext
```

But that's the result I get:

[image]

I suppose it's because the captions have different length. But I can't change the title in the caption, is there a way to make the gap go away?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `minipage`s are not aligned. `minipage` have some optional arguments:

```
\begin{minipage}[pos(c,t,b)][height][contentpos(c,t,b,s)]{width}
    Minipage content
\end{minipage}
```

The longer caption in Figure 3 extends the margins of the `minipage` in both upwards and downwards direction. So if you want the `minipage`s to align, you have to align them at the bottom or at the top - maybe something like

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \minipage[t][][t]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Immagini/teiera-ambientale.png}
        \caption{Componente ambientale}
        \label{fig:Componente ambientale}
        \endminipage\hfill
        \minipage[t][][t]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Immagini/teiera-diffusa.png}
        \caption{Componente ambientale e diffusa}
        \label{fig:Componente ambientale e diffusa}
        \endminipage\hfill
        \minipage[t][][t]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Immagini/teiera-speculare.png}
        \caption{Componente ambientale, diffusa e speculare}
        \label{fig:Componente ambientale, diffusa e speculare}
        \endminipage
    \end{figure}

    \blindtext 


\end{document}
```

Comment: I've found that it works also without blindtext.

Answer (score 2):

The `subcaption` package offers `\subcaptionbox` command, which automatically aligns the sub-figures  by their very first caption line.

Its syntax is:

```
\subcaptionbox[<listentry>]{<heading>}[<width>][<inner-pos>]{<contents>}
\subcaptionbox*{<heading>}[<width>][<inner-pos>]{<contents>}
```

The heading is used for caption.  For further details, see `subcaption` documentation page 6.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \subcaptionbox{Componente ambientale\label{fig:Componente ambientale}}[0.32\textwidth][t]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        }\hfill
        \subcaptionbox{Componente ambientale e diffusa\label{fig:Componente ambientale e 
                  diffusa}}[0.32\textwidth][t]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        }\hfill
        \subcaptionbox{Componente ambientale, diffusa e speculare some text to fill\label{fig:Componente ambientale,
                  diffusa e speculare}}[0.32\textwidth][t]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        }
    \end{figure}

    \blindtext


\end{document}
```

[image]