# Placing three pictures with captions aligned correctly in minipages

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

I need to put three pictures side by side.
From the hint in this post
[How to order 3 images horizontally?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10245/how-to-order-3-images-horizontally), I have this code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering  
    \minipage{0.22\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic/m1}
        \caption{Conventional}\label{fig:model1}
    \endminipage\hspace{1cm}%\hfill
    \minipage{0.22\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic/m2}
        \caption{Knowledge Transfer}\label{fig:model2}
    \endminipage\hspace{1cm}%\hfill
    \minipage{0.22\textwidth}%
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic/m3}
        \caption{Piaget}\label{fig:model3}
    \endminipage
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, with the lengthy caption in the second picture, these pictures are not correctly aligned. How to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write `\begin{minipage}...\end{minipage}` and pass the `t` option for vertical alignment.  This will align the baselines of the first line of each `minipage` with that of the others.  Provided the figures do not descend below the baseline, this will give you a better alignment of the captions:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
      \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{Conventional}\label{fig:model1}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{1cm}%\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm]{example-image-b}
      \caption{Knowledge Transfer}\label{fig:model2}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{1cm}%\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}%
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
      \caption{Piaget}\label{fig:model3}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The `height=` arguments to two of the graphics are just to emphasise the effect.

To improve the formatting of the narrow captions you might consider putting the following in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
```

producing the following instead

[image: Second sample]