# Additional row of minipages inside of a figure

Tags: minipage, alignment

I would reference the following [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10245/how-to-order-3-images-horizontally). I'm interested in ordering mini pages inside of a figure. What I would like to do is to insert another row of mini pages below the given row of 3 subimages, so that I get a figure containing 3 x 2 mini pages.

One row can be done like:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{delete_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image1}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ok_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image2}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{settings_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image3}
\endminipage
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{delete_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image1}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ok_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image2}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{settings_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image3}
\endminipage
\\  
  \minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{delete_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image4}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ok_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image5}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{settings_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image6}
\endminipage

\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would have used a \par instead of \\.  For example, \caption begins and ends with a \par.